# Export my 3D models in 3DS Max to FBX

Tags: unity-game-engine, max, 3ds

Everytime I export my 3D models in 3DS Max to FBX, I get the following error:

Some materials in this scene may not be supported by certain applications and will import as standard gray materials instead. The following materials are affected
and a list of all elements.

How do I properly export 3D models with texture in 3DS Max and import to Unity?

Comment: use standar materials If not render to textures to export.

Comment: Thanks. I tested the standard material and it works fine. It seems FBX exporter does not support other materials!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using other render material than the default. If you export your model with default material it will be exported with no errors.